# Finding points on a face of an icosphere

Tags: coordinates, sphere

I am working on a game the ultimately will be a tactical game on the surface of a sphere. To model the surface of a sphere I have chosen to use an iterated icosphere, where each face is iterated quite a few times.

I have modeled this as an icosphere and have the spherical coordinate of the vertices for all the faces. (Azimuth angle and zenuth angle).

Given this I want to generate the "tactical" view of each of these sectors.  So I have a spherical triangle defined by 3 vertices in spherical coordinates.  I want to break this triangle into a series of points 100 by 100, is SIZE as the actual value is unimportant.

I generate that x,y map and now I need to try to get each sub point back onto the icosphere. That is where I am being thrown. How do I get the spherical coordinate for an x,y location in the sector?

Now the triangles at the very tip of the north pole are easy, but once I get off that then the point of the triangle no longer points toward the pole, and I cannot find a programatic way to convert my field of points.

I know the triangle is an equilateral triangle with a vertex angle of 72 degrees. (spherical triangles are funky that way) I have the coordinates for each vertex. But my math and geometry skills are not sufficient to convert the x,y of a given point in the triangle to the sphere.

I am very new to all this math and so have been doing a lot of research but keep coming up dry.

[EDIT]
Here is an image to help explain.
[image: Icosphere]

The blue is the large division.

The black shows on of the subdivisions where the top point is not pointed toward the pole.

The Red start of a grid is showing the (x,y) points on that face that I want to convert into azimuth angle and zenuth angle on the sphere
as whole.

Does that help?

Comment: Can you show us a diagram of what mapping you want to achieve between the icosphere and the xy plane? There are many different map projections you could be using, so specifying it in detail can help us get you accurate answers quickly.

Comment: Where the new comments enough or do you need more detail?